# Why does 10 ^ 0 equal 10 in Java instead of 1

Tags: java

In Java, why does 10 ^ 0 equal 10? This is 10 to the power of 0, which on any calculator equals 1.

Comment: No, it is not 10 to the power of 0. It's the XOR operator.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`^` does *not* perform exponentation in Java or most other languages with C-like syntax; it performs a bitwise `XOR` (and `XOR`'ing anything with 0 produces the same number as you started with).

If you want to compute *a<sup>b</sup>*, use `Math.pow(a, b)`.

Comment: Oops. I guess I'm not the only one who screwed that up. For some dang reason, the ^ sign is coming out as "power to" in my head. I must have picked that up from some other programming language but can't figure out where.

Comment: LaTeX? Not a prog. language, but the most prominent example I can think of.

Comment: It's a common mistake. Both Matlab, TeX, and Excel macros use this notation, and `^` is commonly used when writing mathematical formulas as text.

Comment: @midor LaTeX is a macro package for TeX, which actually is a Turing-complete programming language (but [not a pleasant one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42749/10196)...)

Answer (score 2):

The operator `^` is bitwise XOR. It's not a power operator. To calculate power, use `Math.pow()`.

Answer (score 1):

That `^` operator is the [XOR operator](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCcQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.programmerinterview.com%2Findex.php%2Fjava-questions%2Fxor-in-java%2F&ei=ij3JVJL-B4megwTelILgDg&usg=AFQjCNGYWVQKvSwxdTeiJlPqS7DTGTl2AA&sig2=GY8sh7BBuWH4l98944geIA&bvm=bv.84607526,d.eXY), not the power function.

To use power, call the Math library function :

```
Math.pow(2,x)
```